# Using different versions of same library

Tags: java, cassandra, guava, cql, hector

I've lately upgraded my Cassandra nodes from version 1.0.11 to version 2.1.8.
Version 1.0.11 uses Hector Java Driver, which isn't supported anymore, whereas for v.2.1.8, we are using Native CQL Driver.

When I've added the libraries for the new version, I've encountered a serious problem with Guava library:

- Hector Driver - works with (legacy) guava-r09.jar.
- Native CQL Driver - works with guava-18.0.jar.

So, I tried to remove the old Guava jar (v.09) and replace it with the new one (v.18), but it's not compliant with Hector, since Hector is pretty much deprecated for a while and is not compatible with newer versions of anything.

On the other hand, Native CQL driver won't work with Guava versions lower than v.18.
And of course, both together will crash the whole system since many functions will override each other.

Some possible solutions I've been thinking about are:

1. Migrating our whole project to new Driver - this is a solution but it will take ages, since we've got a lot of complex code.
2. Deep digging into Hector Classes and manually changing them to be compatible with v.18 - This is another solution, but it will take time and be very risky. Besides, each Guava update I'll need to do modifications which may possibly take much time.
3. Two parallel apps? Can't really figure this one...

Does anyone have any other easier suggestions? Like some sort of selective library version for one query and a different version for others? Maybe some sort of Docker? or perhaps a Virtual Env solution?

Thanks in advance,
Adam.

Comment: the native CQL driver for 2.1.x uses guava 14.0.1 (https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1/pom.xml#L54), but 2.2.0 will use guava 16.0.1.  Does that help your situation?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried using that exact version, hoping that maybe both versions will meet in the middle, but unfortunately Hector isn't compatible with that version too. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You could probably do something with separate classloaders like Tomcat does with webapps (each webapp gets its own classloader) or OSGi, but other than that it's a bit of unexplored territory for me unfortunately :(

Comment: You could shade the guava dependency so that by byte-code relocation there is no conflict. This would be your safest option.

Comment: Ben, thanks for the advice.
Andy, After deep research - I've found out that there is no magical solution in this situation. 
So, I went to the Hector's changelog and I saw that one following release actually uses guava 14.0! So I've upgraded the Thrift client to that version, and downgraded the Guava 18.0 lib to 14.0 - and it actually worked!
So now my app is using Hector + Native CQL.
The downside is that I'm stuck with Cassandra v2.1, since 2.2+ already uses Guava 16.0.1+.
I guess I'll deal with it when I'll need to (in the distant future).
Thanks a lot guys!